# Displaying The Date with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

What I'm trying to do is display the date and time somewhat similar to what you would see within Facebook. However, Xcode is displaying this error:

> use of unresolved identifier 'creator'.

Here's my function I'm having trouble with:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.index = indexPath.row

    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(creator.createdAt)

    return cell
}
```

An error wasn't displaying until I typed out the second to last line of code. Specifically, I know the error is being caused by `creator`, but I also believe that `timestampLabel` is the culprit also because it didn't change a color like the person I was following along with in the video. Now I'm utilizing Parse to store all the users data and `creator` is one of the categories I have in Parse. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I've spent way to long on something that's probably really simple.

Comment: If you know what is causing the error then what is the question? `creator` needs to defined (eg. `var creator = ...`)

Comment: I'm not really sure though because I have everything the same from var to return cell the same as in the example video besides 'creator' this is because the individual in the video used 'swiffer' as a category in their Parse project. This is the video I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qcrO8uNzU The date portion starts at 39:24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is not the timestampLabel. The culprit is the creator object.

> use of unresolved identifier 'creator'

means the object is not defined in the current scope. In your case creator object. creator should be defined.

Assuming from the youtube video and your code `posts` object is an array of parse objects(PFObject)

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    //---------------------------Add this-------------------
    var creator = cell.post as PFObject
    //------------------------------------------------------

    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(creator.createdAt)


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added what you suggested and then I unwrapped createdAt. Another error popped up stating 'value of type 'PostCell' has no member 'timestampLabel''.

Comment: @mur7ay You need to add a timestampLabel (Label) to the custom cell PostCell